# How to validate form element without using reactive forms?

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I want to validate an element without using Reactive Forms, I am using two way binding like below:

```
 <input
                    type="text"
                    class="form-control"
                    autocomplete="off"
                    [required]="fieldDefinition.required"
                    [disabled]="fieldDefinition.disabled"
                    [(ngModel)]="fieldDefinition.fieldvalue"
                />
```

How to highlight elements by red color after clicking on a button if they are required? So, I need to validate all fields after button click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular add the class ng-invalid ng-touched to the inputs with [(ngModel)] -also if you use ReactiveForms

so, you can declare a variable

```
submitted=false;
```

And in button

```
<button (click)="submitted=true">submit</button>
```

Your inputs add the class submitted when the variable becomes true

```
<input [class.submitted]="submitted" ....>
```

And you can define a .css like

```
.submitted.ng-invalid
{
  border-color:red
}
```

You can see a simple example in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ikev6j?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)